# Site is reloading by itself

Tags: jquery, load, reload, getjson

i have the following site, which makes a callback to a different domain.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title> Example Entry Form </title>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getParameters(){
        // login
        //window.showModalDialog('http://localhost:8080/test/login/check.mvc','','dialogWidth:500px; dialogHeight:350px; resizable:no; unandorned:yes; status:no; ');
        //get data
        $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/test/secure/profile/services/export/getuser.mvc?callback=?',function(res){
            alert('Your name is '+res.lname);
            $('#lastname').val(res.lname);
            $('#firstname').val(res.fname);
            $('#club').val(res.club);
            $('#phone').val(res.phone);
            $('#mobile').val(res.mobile);
            $('#mail').val(res.email);
            $('#street_nr').val(res.streetNr);
            $('#zip_city').val(res.zip + " " + res.city);
            $('#birthday').val(res.birthday);
        })
        .error(function(){
            alert("Error");
        })
        .complete(function(){
            alert("Complete");
        });
        alert("Script End!");
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body >

    <h1>Entry Form</h1>

    <table>
     <tr>
      <td style="width:400px;">
        <form action="save.php" id="FormName">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Lastname:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="lastname"/></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td>Firstname:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="firstname"/></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td>Club:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="club"/></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td>Mobile:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="mobile"/></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td>Telephone:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="phone"/></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td>eMail:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="mail"/></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td>Street+Nr:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="street_nr"/></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td>ZIP+City:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="zip_city"/></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td>Birthday:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="birthday"/></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><button type="submit">Send Form</button>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
        <a href="" onclick="getParameters();"><img src="script/pic.png" alt="Get Data"/></a>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

The stated script works fine, except for two major problems:

1. it only works, when there is an alert(); in the script, which is not in the &.getJSON() function.
2. after the last alert(); fires ("End of Script!") the site is reloading (the browser says: http://code.jquery.com/ -> the jquery script) and after being finished. All data are gone.

Why? And how can I fix this?

Comment: Not clear what you mean by a "*callback to a different domain*". Are you talking about the Ajax call? What domain is the page being loaded from in the first place, if not localhost? The **save.php** file referred to by the form would be treated as coming from the same domain as the main page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `onclick="return getParameters();"` and replace `alert` with `return false;` (or was it true?)

Or replace `a` tag with `span`. Or remove it altogether and add `onclick` to the `img`.

What happens now is that you initiate the async request and go on doing what would normally be done when clicking the link.

Comment: Thanks... I found it out myself by browsing and browsing and browsing.  The odd thing was, it worked before, when I used a normal <button> instead of <a>...  But thanks! That was it...
Now I only have to find out WHY showModalDialog opens a href automatically in another window IN IE and not in the current.

Comment: `button` without a form is not supposed to leave the page. No comments about showModalDialog, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Your page is getting redirect because your  tag has an empty href and your function is not stopping your page from redirecting.

It works with alert because alert stops the window from redirecting until you press ok.

As michael suggested try using return false.

But using onClick is a bad practice.

Or you can bind the click handler using jQuery bind (which is a best practice).

Update your html like this:

```
<td valign="top">
        <a href='#' id='someButton'><img src="script/pic.png" alt="Get Data" /></a>
      </td>
```

And then in the script tag, do this:

```
 $('#someButton').bind('click', getParameters);
```

and in your function do this:

```
function getParameters(e){
 ..... // your code here
 e.stopPropagation();
 e.preventDefault();'
}
```

Comment: what do these functions do:
'e.stopPropagation();
 e.preventDefault();'

Comment: They stop event propagation and disable default action.

Comment: But, Shaheer. While I do find your approach alright, I totally don't understand what makes it the *best* practice.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker i was talking about the unobtrusive javascript, this was just an example of it.

Comment: @Shaheer, yes, but whether unobtrusiveness is a better practice for this particular case is not known and unless we're religious we can't really talk of something being "best" here :)

Note, that I still maintain your approach is not any worse ;-)